# Account Team Member lost when Account Owner changes

Tags: account, ownership, account-teams

Not sure if this is a valid question. But, somehow, my understanding is that when the Account's owner is updated, the Account Team Members are lost and not preserved.

I was planning some work around that to possibly fix this but during testing I found this to be incorrect and neither am I able to find some documentation related to this.

Is it possible that it was a known issue at one time or a new feature / API version that has changed this behaviour? I'm trying to remember how I came to think this was the behaviour. Apologies for the non-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox that allows you to keep the account team when changing the owner as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_owner.htm&language=en_US):
[image]

You might be remembering something similar to the idea out [there](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BplnAAC) requesting this be checked by default so account teams aren't accidentally lost when not checked:

> When assigning an account, it is not possible to lock the account
>   team: there is no control on the checkbox "keep account team", and no
>   API access around assignments. (note: maybe one can create an Apex
>   trigger for it, but it wouldn't change the UI of the assignment page)

Edit: Another idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000amOqAAI) also states it is not possible to keep the account teams via API as you thought:

> Allow Keep Account Teams and Keep Sales Team when changing owner via
>   API.  Essentially, if we change the owner via the API we don't have
>   the ability to have the Keep Account Teams and Keep Sales Teams
>   checkboxes checked like you would if you manually changed the owner
>   via the UI.

Edit 2: After testing I also confirmed that the account team is kept when the account owner changes, in the workbench, in the developer console as well as during a jitterbit upload. I found a note at the bottom of the help sheet [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_owner.htm&language=en_US) that does make it sound like it's expected behavior.

> After you change a record’s owner, the previous owner’s visibility
>   reverts to the default sharing setting unless that user is on an
>   account or opportunity team. For example, if the previous owner of an
>   account is on an account team, that user has Read Only or the access
>   specified in your organization-wide default for accounts, whichever is
>   greater. The previous owner’s access to related records remain the
>   same. This behavior is the same for opportunity owners that are
>   members of an opportunity team as long as you change ownership using
>   the API. When you change ownership of an opportunity within
>   Salesforce, you can select the access level you want.

Comment: Definitely possible. But I should mention that my question is from the API perspective.

Comment: @LVS added another idea link out there which specifically talks about the API, and confirms what you thought.

Comment: @LVS can you share how you are going about the testing, I can try it on my end to and see what happens...

Comment: yup. I'm just using workbench to upload a file with Account ID and Owner ID. The update goes through successfully in my sandbox and the AccountTeamMember is preserved. There is no trigger logic on Account. I'm going to test the same in my DE org

Comment: @LVS confirmed the same behavior in my sandbox and it does sound like it's expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone visiting this thread it could be good to know that it's possible to control whether the account team should be deleted when the account owner is updated or whether it should be kept. You can also specify this for other settings, e.g the Sales Team. Simply add *OwnerChangeOptions* to the request header.

For example in SOAPUI, you add this tag to the header if the request and the account team will be preserved:

```
<soapenv:Envelope  
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
<urn:OwnerChangeOptions>
    <urn:options>
      <urn:type>KeepAccountTeam</urn:type>
      <urn:execute>true</urn:execute>
    </urn:options>
</urn:OwnerChangeOptions>
```

More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_ownerchangeoptions.htm).

Comment: ah, version 35.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Below 2 ways can be used to lock account teams while updating owners on accounts

1.manually update the record

2.update owners via mass transfer tool

steps to follow:
setup>mass transfer record>mass transfer accounts

You can refer: [mass transfer records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_transfer.htm&type=5)

There is also an [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpln) posted by other users that you can upvote.

Answer (score 0):

[An open source invocable action is now available](https://unofficialsf.com/advanced-change-owner-configuration-now-available-in-flow-and-apex/) that provides access to all of the OwnerChangeOptions via Flow and Apex.