# How to keep account team members without deleting when changing the owner on Account?

Tags: apex, trigger, account-teams, owner

[image]

**How do i check the "Keep account team members" option always? Or is there any way to achieve this through code or API(s).**

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/account-team-member-lost-when-account-owner-changes?rq=1